# How to change the value STATUS from 1 to 0

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `WRISTBANDS` that is connected to a table called `PARTICIPANTS`.

I want to change the attribute `STATUS` in the `WRISTBANDS` table to INACTIVE (= 0) each time a new line is inserted into the `WRISTBAND` table and is associated with an existing participant in the `WRISTBAND` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg3_after_insert
ON WRISTBANDS
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE WRISTBANDS
    SET STATUS = 0
    WHERE IDPARTICIPANT IN (SELECT IDPARTICIPANT FROM WRISTBANDS)
END 
GO
```

I've tried this way but what happens is that all the records in the table `WRISTBANDS` change their attribute `STATUS` to = 0. And I want the trigger to compare the `IDPARTICIPANT` from the inserted record to all the records in the WRISTBANDS table and if exists the same `IDPARTICIPANT` it should change the record that exists to STATUS = 0.

Hope that I have explained myself. I am new to SQL development, just learning.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you want to set the `status` to `0` for existing records, when they have the same `IDPARTICIPANT` value as the inserted record(s) (please correct me if I'm wrong).

For the purpose of this answer, I'm assuming your `WRISTBANDS` table have a primary key, and it's a single column called `ID` (It would work just the same for a composite primary key, this is an assumption made for simplicity).

So you need to use an update with an inner join between the `WRISTBANDS` table and the `inserted` table (generated for you by SQL Server), like this (Please read the comments in the code for clarifications):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg3_after_insert
ON WRISTBANDS
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 

UPDATE T
SET [Status] = 0 -- status is a reserved word in SQL Server, so use square brackets
FROM WRISTBANDS AS T
JOIN INSERTED AS I -- join is equivalent to inner join
    ON T.IDPARTICIPANT = I.IDPARTICIPANT -- only records with the same IDPARTICIPANT 
WHERE T.Id != I.Id -- only records that was not inserted in he statement that fired this trigger

END
```

Comment: Why not just use `INNER JOIN` in the code? Then your intention is clear and you don't have to explain it in a comment. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand touche :-) Sometimes i write it explicitly, sometimes implicitly. I know it's a bad habit and I should probably write it explicitly every time (or at least be consistent) but in this case I thought it might be just something else the OP is no aware of that I might help with (at least knowing when reading some sql code that a `join` is short-hand for an `inner join`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried it and it works!! Although I didn't explained well, I need that the last record in wristbands that is inserted stays with STATUS=1 and all the others need to change to STATUS = 0.

Comment: Without a column to order by, there is no last record. In a relational database, tables are unsorted by narure.